# Thermionic Emission Conservation of Energy

Tags: electronic-configuration, emission

I am learning about thermionic emission and how it led to the vacuum tube. It is said that thermionic emission was a way to increase the flow of electrons from a signal ([e.g. in a radio](https://youtu.be/0UKCUMghTrc?t=319) receiving a weak signal, boosted by thermionic emission). What I don't understand is how it ["generates" electricity](https://www.frontiersin.org/articles/10.3389/fenrg.2014.00054/full); even if the coil is heated to it's work threshold, wouldn't a coil only be able to emit as many electrons as are supplied?

Thank you for your time

Answer (score 1):

I was mistaken on the principle that governs vacuum tubes. It is not that the signal is being amplified by thermionic emission; rather, the radio wave is being used as a gate to allow or block electrons from being received. Thermions are being emitted from a coil using electricity, emitting at a higher current, modulated by the radio wave as a control grid (preventing or allowing the thermions from being collected at the anode).

Comment: Correct... perhaps delete both question and answer. That said, thermionic emission *can* generate electricity, e.g. https://www.geographynotes.com/energy-management-2/generators/thermionic-generator-with-diagram-energy-conversion-energy-management/4195 , but radio tubes are called "valves" for good reason.